# Powershell Core "Couldn't resolve host name"

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-v6.0

I'm using Powershell 6b5 AppImage on Arch Linux (using the official AppIimage). I have no trouble using IPv4 and IPv6 networking outside of powershell, both URL and IP. However, in PS, when I invoke the following command:

`iwr 'http://google.com'`,

I get

`iwr : Couldn't resolve host name`.

I get the same error when I do the following (the IPv4 address is one of google.com)

`iwr 'http://172.217.26.238'`

Using the IPv6 address, I get a 404, which means that connection works fine:

`iwr 'http://[2404:6800:4009:808::200e]'`

Does anybody have any pointers on how to fix this?